# Why do I need to set execute permissions to run a bash script when it can run if I force it with “bash test.sh?”

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

These are the contents of `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test me"
```

To execute with `bash test.sh`,no problem. But to execute with `./test.sh`,an error occur:

```
bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
```

`chmod u+x test.sh` can make it run with `./test.sh`.

I want to know the reason: Why it is no need to add `chmod u+x test.sh` when to execute it with `bash  test.sh`?

And why it is needed to add `chmod u+x test.sh` when to execute it with `./test.sh`?

Comment: While "why" questions CAN be subject to opinion, in this case, this question has a clear answer (see the answer marked). Further, the marked duplicate is a "how" question and therefore qualitatively different from this question. It is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run it with `bash test.sh` you are explicitly telling bash to load and run `test.sh`. The file only needs to be read to “run” via that method. But if you just run a file with `./test.sh` like that it won’t run because the file has no explicit execute permissions; just read permissons.

Meaning, in the first case `test.sh` is being loaded  by `bash`. But on it’s own, Unix/Linux systems won’t run files by default. And past that, if you remove that initial `#!/bin/bash` from `./test.sh` and try to run it even with execute permissions, it won’t run since the system won’t know to do with the commands beneath it.

And if you are wondering while files don’t automatically get execute permissions on creation? Well, that’s a long conversation but basically doing something like that would create a new attack surface on your system. If someone can get on your system and just execute files by writing them, that is a very big problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike CP/M-inspired operating systems like DOS and Windows, Unix doesn't use filenames to indicate which files are executable.

If you want to run a file using the OS call '[execvpe()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvpe)' or by naming it on the command-line it needs to have execute permission

So long as it has the execute bit set you call call it anything you want eg: `trump.gif`  or `foo-script` (but `test` is not a good example name as there's already a command with that name)

Comment: Yes, the file should NOT be named "test" since that is a command name.